# How to trigger event from a control inside of a GridView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm looking for the right way to trigger an event that will reset my label's text.

My GridView has a row defined the following way:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtgvEmailAddress" Text = '<%# Eval("EMAIL")%>' runat="server" Width="200px" onclick="ResetMessage()"/>
```

By doing that, `onclick` event is highlighted with a message saying that `onclick` is invalid attribute for element "TextBox". However it works fine on a page. But, I want to get rid of that error and do it the right way.

GridView renders a table.

The following is a table:

```
<div>
<table cellspacing="0" id="MainContent_GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$CustID&#39;)">Customer ID</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$CustFirstName&#39;)">First Name</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$CustLastName&#39;)">Last Name</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$CustCity&#39;)">City</a></th><th scope="col">Email</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblCustID_0">12</span>
        </td><td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblFirstName_0">Anders</span>
        </td><td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblLastName_0">Rohansen</span>
        </td><td>
         <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblCity_0">Takoma Park</span>
       </td><td>
         <input name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl02$txtEmail" type="text" value="a.rohansen@testemail.com" id="MainContent_GridView1_txtEmail_0" />
          <span data-val-controltovalidate="MainContent_GridView1_txtEmail_0" data-val-errormessage="Must enter Email Address" data-val-validationGroup="grpEmail" id="MainContent_GridView1_ctl00_0" data-val="true" data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val-initialvalue="" style="visibility:hidden;">Must enter Email Address</span>
           <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl02$btnUpdate" value="Update Email" onclick="return ValidateEmail(this);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl02$btnUpdate&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;grpEmail&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="MainContent_GridView1_btnUpdate_0" ButtonType="Button" />

         </td>
    </tr><tr style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblCustID_1">8</span>
        </td><td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblFirstName_1">Deborah</span>
        </td><td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblLastName_1">Damien</span>
        </td><td>
         <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblCity_1">Fresno</span>
       </td><td>
         <input name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl03$txtEmail" type="text" value="d.damien@testemail.com" id="MainContent_GridView1_txtEmail_1" />
          <span data-val-controltovalidate="MainContent_GridView1_txtEmail_1" data-val-errormessage="Must enter Email Address" data-val-validationGroup="grpEmail" id="MainContent_GridView1_ctl00_1" data-val="true" data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val-initialvalue="" style="visibility:hidden;">Must enter Email Address</span>
           <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl03$btnUpdate" value="Update Email" onclick="return ValidateEmail(this);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl03$btnUpdate&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;grpEmail&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="MainContent_GridView1_btnUpdate_1" ButtonType="Button" />

         </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblCustID_2">7</span>
        </td><td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblFirstName_2">Derek</span>
        </td><td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblLastName_2">Chaddick</span>
        </td><td>
         <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblCity_2">Fairfield</span>
       </td><td>
         <input name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl04$txtEmail" type="text" value="d.chaddick@testemail.com" id="MainContent_GridView1_txtEmail_2" />
          <span data-val-controltovalidate="MainContent_GridView1_txtEmail_2" data-val-errormessage="Must enter Email Address" data-val-validationGroup="grpEmail" id="MainContent_GridView1_ctl00_2" data-val="true" data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val-initialvalue="" style="visibility:hidden;">Must enter Email Address</span>
           <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl04$btnUpdate" value="Update Email" onclick="return ValidateEmail(this);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl04$btnUpdate&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;grpEmail&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="MainContent_GridView1_btnUpdate_2" ButtonType="Button" />

         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
 </div>
```

What is the best way to reset label as soon as a email field is clicked?

Comment: So everything is working fine, and all you want is just ot get ird of the warning?

Comment: Yes, looks like the way I do it with `onclick` defined on a text field, gives me a warning. I'm looking for the way to bind `onclick` event to  all the email text fields, so when I click it I have the same functionality as I have now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little surprising may be, but this is the right way to do it. Here is some explanation form [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ytf5t7k%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) (actually this article is about doing the very same thing but with another control):

> Any attribute/value pairs in the control's markup that do not
>   correspond to control properties are passed through to the browser as
>   is.

So basically what happens is that you are setting a nonexisting attribute to the control. ASP.NET does not recognize this attribute and gives you a warning about it. However it does not mean that there is an error - as you have said yourself everything is working fine. ASP.NET merely tries to ensure that you are not doing something wrong. However this attribute is something you have written intentionally - you can leave it, and it will be rendered as is in the resulting HTML.

If it was not inside a data bound control, a more preferable way of doing it would be setting an `Attributes` collection:

```
TextBox1.Attributes["onclick"]="ResetMessage();";
```

But since you are not able to retrieve your control by ID directly, you can either go with `FindControl` or set attribute in the markup - both are good options.

Last slight comment - add a semicolon to the end of the js.

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation, @Andrei. I just was looking everywhere for an answer.

Comment: @eugene.it, please see the edit with some more info on the subject